# Running test for Http.post and app-console content for blank ID passed

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am running test for angular app, when I don't  pass any data to this api it displays "No Data to be returned" and when I pass accountID it returns JSON format of entire account detail.

I want to test if the text displayed inside app-console is indeed "No Data to be returned" when blank accountId is passed.

**component.ts**

```
loadData() {
    this.http.post('/api/accountid', this.record)
    .subscribe(res => {
        const status = res['status'];
        if (res['status'] == "FAILURE") {
          this.consoleMessages="No Data to be returned"; 
         else {
          this.consoleMessages = "Sucess" + JSON.stringify(res);

          });

        }
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        this.consoleMessages = "No Data to be returned";
      }
    );
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" for="name">Account Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-3" 
    [(ngModel)]="record.accountid" name="accountid">
    <button (click)="loadData()">Load</button>
</div>

<app-console [consoleMessages]="consoleMessages"></app-console>
```

Comment: Can you please share what you have so far in your component.spec.ts file?